# Does component testing mean only checking the component's rendering output?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have question regarding component testing in React native, does it solely involve verifying the component's rendering output, without concerning implementation details such as API call?

For instance, suppose there's a **list screen** that makes an API call to retrieve **list of item data**, and this screen has three potential states: **loading, data, and success**. Different UI components are used for these states, including **loading placeholders, an error view, and a data view**. Should component testing focus on confirming the rendered UI for each state without mocking the API call?

And should API call mocking be reserved for integration testing, particularly when combining multiple components (e.g., login, registration, and forgot password screens) into a single authentication flow?

sample code -

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Button } from 'react-native';

const ListScreen = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      // Simulate an API call
      const response = await fetch('https://example.com/api/items');
      const data = await response.json();
      setData(data);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  if (error) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Error: {error.message}</Text>
        <Button title="Retry" onPress={fetchData} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View style={{ padding: 16 }}>
            <Text>{item.name}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default ListScreen;
```